# cordova-file -transfer ios path?

Tags: ios, file, cordova, devextreme, phonegap

My codes are this way. These codes work with android. But it does not work in ios. Because the path is wrong. 
What is the path?
fileName is variable

```
onFileSaving: function (fileWillCreate) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, function (dirEntry) {
                dirEntry.getFile(fileWillCreate.fileName + '.xlsx', { create: true, exclusive: false },
                 function (fileEntry) {
                     fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

                         fileWriter.onwriteend = function () {
                             console.log("Dosya yazıldı:" + fileEntry.fullPath);

                             alert('Dosyanız Başarıyla Kaydedildi'+fileEntry.fullPath);
                         };

                         fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                             console.log("Dosya yazılırken hata oluştu: " + e.toString());
                         };

                         fileWriter.write(fileWillCreate.data);

                     })
                 })
            })
        }
```

Comment: Hi @onur! Did my answer help you solve your problem? If so, can you [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark? This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory`. This file-system directory is Android-only as you can see in the plugin [docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files).

> `cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory` - Application space
>   on external storage. **(Android)**

To solve this problem you can put your files in one of the cross-platform file-system directories available in the plugin interface (e.g. `cordova.file.dataDirectory`) and use it instead of `cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory` or add a `if` in your code to use the file-system directory according the platform.